# How to host a PHP file with AWS?

Tags: php, amazon-web-services

After many hours of reading documentation and messing around with Amazon Web Services. I am unable to figure out how to host a PHP page.

Currently I am using the S3 service for a basic website, but I know that this service does not support dynamic pages. I was able to use the Elastic Beanstalk to make the Sample Application running PHP. But i have really no idea how to use it. I read up on some other services but they don't seem to do what I want or they are just way to confusing.

**So what I want to be able to do is host a website with amazon that has dynamic PHP pages. Is this possible and what services do you use?**

Comment: Create an EC2 instance. It will, for the most part, work just like a regular server.

Comment: Thank you, ill have to look at this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For a PHP app, you really have two choices in AWS.

Elastic Beanstalk is a service that takes your code, and manages the runtime environment for you - once you've set it up, it's very easy to deploy, and you don't have to worry about managing servers - AWS does pretty much everything for you.  You have less control over the environment, but if your server will run in EB then this is a pretty easy path.

EC2 is closer to conventional hosting.  You need to decide how your servers are configured & deployed (what packages get installed, what version of linux, instance size, etc), your system architecture (do you have separate instances for cache or database, whether or not you need a load balancer, etc) and how you manage availability and scalability (multiple zones, multiple data centers, auto scaling rules, etc).

Now, those are all things that you can use - you dont have to.  If you're just trying to learn about php in AWS, you can start with a single EC2 instance, deploy your code, and get it running in a few minutes without worring about any of the stuff in the previous paragraph.  Just create an instance from the Amazon Linux AMI, install apache & php, open the appropriate ports in the firewall (AKA the EC2 security group), deploy your code, and you should be up & running.

Comment: We are probably going to go with the EC2 since this app will become a lot larger over time. As for hooking up a mysql database, i noticed that the server i picked had mysql installed. Do i just use that or do i use some of the other aws services for databases?

Comment: There's a bit of incorrect information here. AWS offers raw EC2, as well as Elastic Beanstalk and OpsWorks. The latter two achieve the same goal in different ways, so use the one that works best for you. Secondly, if you use *any* of these services, you always have access to the raw resources under the hood (i.e., you can SSH into the EC2 instances in the EB environment). Lastly, if you just want to launch something, EB is EC2 + Deployment. Using raw EC2 is more effort. You can always configure your EB instance(s) using the `.ebextensions` functionality.

Comment: @RyanParman - I didn't realize that you could access the underlying instances running EB.  I guess you learn something every day.

Comment: Right. Other providers give you a "black box". With Elastic Beanstalk and OpsWorks, you can access all of the underlying architecture — instances, security groups, load balancers, auto scaling groups/triggers, etc.

Answer (score 3):

Your Php must run on EC2 machines.

Amazon provides great tools to make life easy (Beanstalk, ECS for Docker ...) but at the end, you own EC2 machines.

There is no a such thing where you can put your Php code without worrying about anything else ;-(

Comment: This is no longer a true statement:  https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/apn/aws-lambda-custom-runtime-for-php-a-practical-example/

Comment: I am not sure you can use lambda as a public HTTP web server, isnit?

Comment: API Gateway + Lambda is the basis of the whole serverless / event driven architectural approach.

Comment: true, that means for a visitor page load => AWS will run a serverless resource? I am really curious to see a whole site hosted this way, any example?

Comment: There are a number of them out there - I know Eric Hammond (alestic.com) has published detailed breakdown of monthly costs for one of his sample applications.

Comment: give a blog link and a public URL please.

Answer (score 0):

If you are having problems hosting PHP sites on AWS then you can go with a service provider like Cloudways. They provide managed AWS servers with one click installs of PHP frameworks and CMS.